# How can I make Minecraft PE on iOS forget my xboxlive account so I can start with a new account?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

I've tried deleting Minecraft PE (which should delete all associated data from the device) but when I reinstall and try to sign up, it magically remembers my old account. It brings up a webview dialog that connects to sisu.xboxlive.com

Comment: You can simply log out if you want to set up a new account.

Answer (score 1):

Non-intuitively, clearing Safari cookies did the trick. It was the webview that was holding onto the account details, not something in the app's sandboxed data store.